# Correct regex not matching anything

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

pattern = r"/destination=(-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)/"
url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=12.1234567890,-12.1234567890"
result = re.search(pattern, url)
latitude = result.group(1)
longitude = result.group(2)
```

I expect to receive the latitude and longtitude output, but Python says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. I tested my regex on regex101 and it works, but I have no clue why is it not working in Python.

Comment: In your own words, why do you think the pattern `/destination=(-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)/` should match? In particular, what do you think is the purpose of the `/` at the beginning and end of the regex? Do you see similar `/` in those places in the text that will be matched? If you were expecting these to be part of the syntax for regexes, that is simply wrong. Python **does not have a syntax for regexes**. The regex engine takes in **ordinary strings**, which can be created in any of the usual ways. The `r` stands for "raw", **not** "regex".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `/` at the beginning/end of the pattern:

```py
import re

pattern = r"destination=(-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)"
url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=12.1234567890,-12.1234567890"
result = re.search(pattern, url)
latitude = result.group(1)
longitude = result.group(2)

print(latitude)
print(longitude)
```

Prints:

```
12.1234567890
-12.1234567890
```

Comment: May I ask why is that happening? Is python taking the slash as an escaped character?

Comment: @Mint No, `/` is normal character - so the pattern doesn't match your URL.